# Add a value in a column as a function of the timestamp and another column

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

The title may not be very clear, but with an example I hope it would make some sense.

I would like to create an output column (called "outputTics"), and put a 1 in it 0.21 seconds after a 1 appears in the "inputTics" column.
As you see, there is no value 0.21 seconds exactly after another value, so I'll put the 1 in the outputTics column two rows after : an example would be at the index 3, there is a 1 at 11.4 seconds so I'm putting an 1 in the output column at 11.6 seconds

- If there is a 1 in the "inputTics" column 0.21 second of earlier, do not put a one in the output column : an example would be at the index 1 in the input column

Here is an example of the red column I would like to create.

[image]

Here is the code to create the dataframe :

```
A = pd.DataFrame({"Timestamp":[11.1,11.2,11.3,11.4,11.5,11.6,11.7,11.8,11.9,12.0,12.1,12.2,12.3,12.4,12.5,12.6,12.7,12.8,12.9,13.0],
                  "inputTics":[0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1],
                  "outputTics":[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]})
```

You can use pd.Timedelta if you can to avoid python rounded numbers if you want

Comment: Can I ask, is the Timestamp always increasing by some predictable amount of time, i.e 0.1 each row? If so the problem is considerably simpler.

Comment: @Alan not at all, it's not linear

Comment: @Lukx Can you write an equation or a statement explaining when you want to have a 1 in outputTics? To be more precise why did you add a 1 in the row with 11.6 as Timestamp?

Comment: @r0ot293 As you see, there is no value 0.11 seconds exactly after another value, so I'll put the 1 in the outputTics column in the next row : an example would be at the index 3, there is a 1 at 11.4 seconds so I'm putting an 1 in the output column at 11.6 seconds

Comment: @Lukx so you wouldn't have added 1 in 11.6 if there was a 1 in inputTics at 11.51?

Answer (score 0):

Create the column with zeros.

```
df['outputTics'] = 0
```

Define a function set_output_tic in the following manner

```
def set_output_tic(row):
    if row['inputTics'] == 0:
        return 0
    index = df[df == row].dropna().index
    # check for a 1 in input within 0.11 seconds
    t = row['Timestamp'] + pd.TimeDelta(seconds = 0.11)
    indices = df[df.Timestamp <= t].index
    c = 0
    for i in indices:
      if df.loc[i,'inputTics'] == 0:
         c = c + 1
      else:
         c = 0
         break
    if c > 0:
      df.loc[indices[-1] + 1, 'outputTics'] = 1 
    return 0
```

then call the above function using df.apply

```
temp = df.apply(set_output_tic, axis = 1) # temp is practically useless
```

Answer (score 0):

This was actually kinda tricky, but by playing with indices in numpy you can do it.

```
# Set timestamp as index for a moment
A = A.set_index(['Timestamp'])
```

```
# Find the timestamp indices of inputTics and add your 0.11
input_indices = A[A['inputTics']==1].index + 0.11


# Iterate through the indices and find the indices to update outputTics
output_indices = []
for ii in input_indices:

    # Compare indices to full dataframe's timestamps
    # and return index of nearest timestamp

    oi = np.argmax((A.index - ii)>=0)
    output_indices.append(oi)
```

```
# Create column of output ticks with 1s in the right place
output_tics = np.zeros(len(A))
output_tics[output_indices] = 1

# Add it to dataframe
A['outputTics'] = outputTics

# Add condition that if inputTics is 1, outputTics is 0
A['outputTics'] = A['outputTics'] - A['inputTics']

# Clean up negative values
A[A['outputTic']<0] = 0

# The first row becomes 1 because of indexing; change to 0
A = A.reset_index()
A.at[0, 'outputTics'] = 0
```